# Decide if number is Armstrong number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just recently started reading the python.org documents and it looked like a really interesting language. Now, since Visual Studio 2017 supports Python, I decided to finally actually start learning it. My friend challenged me to write a program that checks if a number is an Armstrong number.

```
import sys

def isArmstrong(number):
    arr = str(number)
    count = len(arr)
    res = 0
    for x in range(0, count):
        res += int(arr[x]) ** count
    return res == number

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    arg = sys.argv[1]
    print(arg + " is an armstrong number: " + str(isArmstrong(int(arg))))
else:
    print("No arguments passed! :-(");
```

Now this is the first solution that I could come up with. As you can see, it converts the number to a string to determine the amount of digits, and then handle them individually. Is this the smartest way to do it, or can it be done without converting to a string? If not: Is there anything I can do to improve this code performance-wise?

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to Code Review!  I would find something like this easier to read if it explained what an [Armstrong number](https://illuminations.nctm.org/Lesson.aspx?id=2166) is.  Saves a trip to Google.

Comment: @mdfst13 You're right, that would've been smart. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

By [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions), Python's official style guide, function names should generally be `lower_case_with_underscores`.  Also, the final semicolon should be omitted.

The function would typically be written more elegantly using the [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set) builtin function, with a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions).  (It's not any faster than your original code, though.  Actually, a tiny bit slower.)

I don't recommend using `arr` as a variable name, since it's neither descriptive (what does the array represent?) nor accurate (it's actually a string).

For the printout, I recommend using [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) or one of the other formatting mechanisms.

```
import sys

def is_armstrong(number):
    digits = str(number)
    length = len(digits)
    return number == sum(int(digit) ** length for digit in digits)

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    arg = int(sys.argv[1])
    print('{} is an Armstrong number? {}'.format(arg, is_armstrong(arg)))
else:
    print("No arguments passed! :-(")
```

Comment: Wow, that style guide is really useful. Also had never heard of `.format()` or `sum()`, thanks for all this! Also I called it "arr" because I'm used to `char[]` for character arrays in C# haha

Comment: The only change I'd make to this answer is to use f-strings, ie `f'{arg} is an Armstrong number? {is_armstrong(arg}'`. The advantage is pretty obvious. It just looks so much nicer. The only downside is they need python 3.6 or newer.